# Set of structs in Go

Tags: struct, go, set

If I have a number of structs that I want to store:

```
type Stuff struct {
    a string
    b string
}
```

I can do it with a slice, but it seems like it would use less memory to use a proper set structure.

Unfortunately Go doesn't have a set structure. Everyone recommends using `map[Stuff]struct{}` but that doesn't work because `Stuff` is a struct. Anyone have any good solutions? Ideally without having to download a library.

Comment: Map [does work](http://play.golang.org/p/TjCDqfmTzx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually set and map data structures require more memory than storing a list of values in plain array or slice as set and map provide additional features efficiently like uniqueness or value retrieval by key.

If you want minimal memory usage, simply store them in a slice, e.g. `[]Stuff`. If you use the values in multiple places, it might also be profitable to just store their pointers, e.g. `[]*Stuff` and so each places that store the same `Stuff` values can store the same pointer (without duplicating the value).

If you only want to store unique struct values, then indeed the set would be the most convenient choice, in Go realized with a `map`.

There's nothing wrong with `map[Stuff]struct{}`, it works. The [requirement for the key type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) for maps:

> The [comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice.

`Stuff` is a struct, and [structs in Go are comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) if:

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) fields are equal.

If your `Stuff` struct is what you posted, it is comparable: it only contains fields of the comparable type `string`.

Also note that if you want a set data structure, it's clearer if you use `bool` as the value type (e.g. `map[Stuff]bool`) and `true` as the value, and then you can simply use [indexing](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) to test if a value is in the map as the index expression yields the zero value of the value type (`false` for `bool`) if the key (`Stuff` in your case) is not in the map, properly telling the value you're looking for is not in the "set". (And if it is in the map, its associated `true` value is the result of the index expression - properly telling it is in the map).

Comment: Ah thanks, I guess it was because some of the fields in my real code are not comparable.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you have a huge set and hurting for memory, you can save a tiny bit of ram using `map[Stuff]struct{}` instead of `bool` and check using `if _, ok := m[Stuff{"a", "b"}]; ok { .... }`

Answer (score 0):

As icza said, a map of structs is a valid option.

But instead of implementing the Set yourself, I would use one of the new generic implementations that are out there since Go 1.18.

See this one for example: https://github.com/amit7itz/goset

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/amit7itz/goset"
)

type Stuff struct {
    a string
    b string
}

func main() {
    set := goset.NewSet[Stuff]()
    set.Add(Stuff{a: "1", b: "2"})
    set.Add(Stuff{a: "2", b: "3"})
    set.Add(Stuff{a: "2", b: "3"})
    
    fmt.Println(set) // Set[main.Stuff]{{2 3} {1 2}}
    fmt.Println(set.Len()) // 2
}
```

Comment: Better to use native map rather than 3rd party lib.