# map[gorm.DB]struct{}{} gives invalid map key type gorm.DB

Tags: dictionary, go, key, go-gorm, hashable

I'd like to create a "set" of gorm types used in my application. So I'd like to define a `map` with my types [`gorm.DB`](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/main.go#L13) as keys and empty `structs{}` as flags:

```
var (
    autoMigrations map[gorm.DB]struct{}
)
```

But compiler doesn't allow me do this with error: `invalid map key type gorm.DB`. I can fool it using pointers to `gorm.DB`s like:

```
map[*gorm.DB]struct{}
```

But it's not a solution, because I need to make it unique and if my map gets filled like `db.AutoMigrate(&Chat{})` I can get lots of similar object with different addresses.

Another solution is to make a slice of `gorm.DB`:

```
autoMigrations []gorm.DB
```

But I have to filter elements on addition manually, which seems insane a little bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only use types as keys in a map that are [comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators). [Spec: Map types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)

> The [comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice.

`gorm.DB` is a struct, and struct values are only comparable if all their fields are comparable:

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) fields are equal.

But `gorm.DB` has e.g. a `DB.values` field which is a map type, and maps are not comparble, and thus `gorm.DB` values are not comparable either, and so you can't use it as map keys.

If you want to create a set of types, you should use [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) as the map keys, which you can acquire using [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) from a value of that type.

A little trick, if you want a `reflect.Type` without having to create a value of the type in question, you can start from a pointer value of that type (which may be `nil`), and use `Type.Elem()` to get the `reflect.Type` descriptor of the pointed type.

For example, to get the `reflect.Type` descriptor of a struct type `Point struct{ X, Y int }` without actually creating / having a `Point`:

```
type Point struct{ X, Y int }
tpoint := reflect.TypeOf((*Point)(nil)).Elem()
fmt.Println(tpoint)
```

Which prints `main.Point`. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Bo-IYcZ8a2).

See related questions:

[How can I prevent a type being used as a map key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916647/how-can-i-prevent-a-type-being-used-as-a-map-key/37919268#37919268)

[Why can't Go slice be used as keys in Go maps pretty much the same way arrays can be used as keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900696/why-cant-go-slice-be-used-as-keys-in-go-maps-pretty-much-the-same-way-arrays-ca/37901853#37901853)

[Set of structs in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786552/set-of-structs-in-go/34786725#34786725)

Comment: Excellent answer! Has Go someway to define own comparing function? Like `__hash__` in Python? this way I can make them comparable.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky No it does not. You can't write custom comparator functions that would automatically be used by the Go runtime.